# Bash script to ssh into computers run a command and direct output to append to a .txt on server

Tags: macos, bash, shell, ssh

How would I go about creating a Bash script that will ssh into a list of computers and run a command and have the output of that command append to a file on the server?

Comment: `for ip in list of ips; do ssh ip 'yourcommand >> yourfile'; done;`

Comment: Or if you mean the on a file on the server you're runnning on: `for ip in list of ips; do ssh ip 'yourcommand' >> yourfile; done;`

Comment: How do I direct it to a .txt file full of the ups or hostnames I want to ssh in? I see you said "for ip in list of ips" but how do I direct it to that list or file that has the ips and assign that ip to the "do ssh ip" ?

Answer (score 1):

*posting this as an answer since I do not have the required reputation for making comments...*

You should use the following shell syntax :

```
for ip in $(<filename.txt); do ssh "$ip" 'yourcommand >> yourfile'; done;
```

**Pro tip:** If you foresee doing this a lot -- you have a bunch of servers on which you must routinely issue commands, capture output, whatever -- it would pay to setup and use [Ansible](http://www.ansible.com) or any of the commonly available infra orchestration tools like Chef/Puppet etc. The reason I recommend ansible is that it requires minimal setup, and that too only on the master machine. It also supports ad-hoc commands pretty well.

Ps: I do not have experience with Chef/Puppet, I've just used Ansible.

Comment: The ansible command to accomplish what you want would be `ansible -i <inventory-file-with-list-of-servers> all -u <username> -m shell -a "yourcommand >> yourfile"`